# How can I download the preview of this book using wget or some other tool?

Tags: windows, pdf, download, wget

So I want to download the preview of the book here with wget in pdf format or jpeg format (a jpeg picture for each page) since the download option isn't available:

https://ofppt.scholarvox.com/reader/docid/88880108/page/1?searchterm=Packt%20Publishing

But when I try to do that, with

`wget https://ofppt.scholarvox.com/reader/docid/88880108/page/1?searchterm=Packt%20Publishing`

all I get is a 10 kb file that I can't open with anything. Please, People who are used to use wget, can you help me on this?
If I can't do this with wget, how can can I do this?
I've thought about doing screenshots, but I want to download the preview of multiple books, and if I screenshot this is going to take forever. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: The preview only show the table of contents. If you want to read the book you should buy it.

Comment: Moral issues aside, there's a lot of client side logic happening when you visit this link, before the image becomes available for download. If you're interested, use the developer plugin and visit the link to see everything happening. You're therefore unlikely to be able to download using a simple cURL or wget request. Although it would almost certainly be a more efficient use of time to flip burgers for enough time to pay for an honest copy of the book, if you are interested in learning, have a look at Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You may download the preview by, for example, in Chrome do a *Save As* the complete
page.

Or you can print it to a PDF printer.

However, you are not going to get more than this website intended you to see,
which is cut-off after the table of contents.